# how to initialize inline form set for admin page

Tags: django-admin

I'm trying to initialize an inline formset of a django 1.8 admin page when a new BookStore object is created, a number of default books will be already listed:

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
class BookInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    form = BookForm
    extra = 1

    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        formset = super(BookInlineAdmin, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
        BookFormSet = formset_factory(BookForm, extra=4)
        formset = BookFormSet(initial=[
            {'stype': 'comic', 'name': 'abc'},
            {'stype': 'drama', 'name': 'aaa'}])
        return formset
```

However, it is failing:

> TypeError: 'BookFormFormSet' object is not callable

How can I initialize the inline form set for admin page?

Comment: I'm also looking for this, have you fixed this requirement?